# Use of keep dense_rank to find a single value

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

My query is something like:

```
select
  name,
  color,
  min(age) keep (dense_rank first order by priority asc) as age
from
  myTable
group by
  name, 
  color
```

I understand that rank and dense_rank will return "duplicate" values in a partition. In my case, if a priority is shared among 2 ages.

so what will the line do:

```
  min(age) keep (dense_rank first order by priority asc) as age
```

Will it pick a row with the smallest priority for a given name,color, and return that corresponding age? If there are two such rows with the same priority, will it just pick one of the rows at random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, if the first priority in the list has multiple age values associated with it, it's the `min(age)` that determines which one to display. You could swap that out for `max(age)` if you wanted the highest age displayed, instead of the lowest.

Answer (score 3):

For a given name and color it will find rows with the lowest priority and among these rows it will find the lowest age. See this, it is quite clear from your example populated with some data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d765f/2